Help Diagnosing Chimney Leak?
So I recently purchased a new home, which has a "double wide" chimney stack with two flues, one for my downstairs living room fireplace and one for my upstairs one in the bedroom right above it. I got it inspected a few months ago, and got a clean bill of health. But then the spring rain started and I noticed water coming into ONLY the upstairs fireplace during a big rain, but not the downstairs one. I called my inspector back out and he went on the roof and sealed up some cracks in the cap, some blemishes in the mortar, etc. but he didn't think see anything major. This didn't fix the problem and it leaked a few weeks later, so he thinks I need to re-point from the roof line up.
I'm trying to avoid this expensive repair if I can - I'm curious why the water is only coming into the one flue and it only happens when there is a significant amount of rain (like over the course of a few days) - never when there's a one-off storm. It must not be coming in from the cap or that would leak during any rain, I would think. Does this mean the bricks need to be saturated before they leak? We'd like to try a DIY fix before I drop $3K+ on a re-point - any ideas there? I'm thinking maybe getting up there myself and doing some mortar patching, maybe spraying on a breathable siloxane sealant to see if that prevents saturation.
Here are some pictures of the chimney and a video of the leak. Curious to hear thoughts!

Does water bead up on the masonry and cap or soak in? The leak I had was caused by seepage through the masonry and applying a sealant took care of the problem. (Sealwall Tuff Stuff worked for me. There are plenty of other products out there.) Every few years I wire brush any problem areas on the cap, caulk cracks and flashing as needed, and reapply sealant. (The house was built by an architect who figured he could be the G.C. and save some money. It shows.)

Thanks @HABO. Unfortunately I haven't really been able to observe what's going on up there because it's a high roof and I've only been here a few months. My guess is that it's soaking in, and that it only gets into the interior when it's a really saturating rain. I'm inclined to agree on the sealant - I think I'm gonna' take a stab at sealing and caulking obvious problem spots before I go with the more drastic and expensive re-pointing measure. May at least buy myself a few years! Thanks for the advice!

The chimney cap should have an overhang and a drip edge.

There are some big cracks by the short stack on top of the chimney. You haven't told us which is the leaking stack. Your picture doesn't show the other side either, so this is a bit of a guess. However there isn't any visual proof that any previous attempt was made to seal cracks.
I would seal up any cracks and the edge of the mortar with a polyurethane caulk. (See areas highlighted in yellow in the pic. There may also be other once you inspect closely.)  If the mortar joints are deeply recessed, they probably need to be repointed also. (Again the pics do not show a clear view of the true condition.)
My gut feeling is the Inspector is right and to get this corrected you will have to pay up. Just get a warranty in writing so if there is still a leak you don't have to pay more.


Thanks for looking @RMDman. Yes, unfortunately those are the only photos I have as I haven't actually gotten up onto the roof yet myself. Yes, that shorter stack on the left is the one that leads to the leaky fireplace. A few questions for you... when you're referring to cracks to you mean on the crown branching out from the short stack? I paid the inspector to fill those top cracks, that's the shiny material on there. I would think if it's still leaking from the top it would leak any time it rains and not just during lengthy/saturating  rains, no? Maybe not.

Also @RMDman, is it OK to use regular polyurethane caulk on a chimney or do I need something heat-resistant with the heat that comes out of there? Or is that not a concern on the exterior bricks at the top? Maybe it doesn't get hot enough.

My experience with these type of leaks is; if it rains light to moderate, but for longer times the rain spreads over surfaces slowly and finds cracks and voids.  A hard driving rain puts water on a surface that is drawn down with the greater amount of rain and is actually pulled away from smaller cracks.  It's weird, but I have had similar issues.

The top of the chimney cap does not get that hot.

You're awesome, thanks @RMDman. Ok, yeah I paid $200 for him to seal those cap cracks and he even took another pass at it after the leak so it would be disappointing if the top is still leaking. But I'll have to get up there and take another look at the top, in addition to caulking along the poor brick mortar joints. I figure it's worth the $10 attempt before a re-pointing conversation. Thanks again for the advice!
